# Diretivas do Blade (Laravel 5.6) dentro do elemento slot do Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

Criei uma diretiva do Blade chamada `@permissao` que simplesmente verifica se na sessão do usuário existe determinado valor, para poder mostrar ou esconder um link do menu.

O menu eu criei como um componente do Vue chamado `menu-item`, dessa forma:

```html
<template>
    <li class="sub-menu">
        <a href="javascript:;">
            <i class="fas" :class="icone"></i>
            <span>{{ titulo }}</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <slot></slot>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
```

Aí no arquivo de layout `app.blade.php`, eu chamo o componente da seguinte forma:

```html
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <menu-item titulo="Usuários" icone="fa-user">
        <li><a href="{{ route('usuarios.index') }}">Listar Usuários</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('usuarios.permissoes') }}">Permissões</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('usuarios.grupos') }}">Grupos</a></li>
    </menu-item>
    <menu-item titulo="Clientes" icone="fa-users">
        <li><a href="{{ route('clientes.index') }}">Listar Clientes</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('clientes.pedidos') }}">Pedidos</a></li>
        @permissao('gerente')
            <li><a href="{{ route('clientes.importar') }}">Importar</a></li>
        @endpermissao
    </menu-item>
</ul>
```

Ou seja, todos os `li` serão compilados no `<slot></slot>`.
E apenas o usuário que tiver a permissão "**gerente**" vai poder ver o item "**Importar**" do menu.

O problema é que se eu faço o login no sistema como um **gerente**, eu vejo o item **Importar**, mas se depois eu logar como um usuário normal (em outro navegador ou computador), eu continuo vendo o item.

Entretanto, se eu faço alguma modificação no arquivo `app.blade.php` e subo pro servidor novamente, o item do menu finalmente some.

Mas aí, se alguém logar como **gerente**, ele também não vai ver o item, a menos que eu altere o arquivo e suba novamente.
Isso acontece tanto em ambiente de desenvolvimento quanto em produção.

Provavelmente o problema tem a ver com cache, ou algo específico do Vue. Sei que eu poderia implementar essa permissão diretamente no componente do Vue, mas existe alguma forma de resolver o problema mantendo a mesma estrutura?

Comment: Eu acho que você está misturando as coisas, `server side` e `front end` ou a tela é gerado por um ou por outro. Deve ser isso, qualquer coisa além dessa opinião seria errado até eu colocar como resposta.

Comment: Ou pode ser alguma palavra com maiúscula e outra com minúscula. Já tive problemas com servidores PHP com configuração Case Sensitive ligada. Tive esse problema com colunas em tabela do Banco de Dados. Eu tinha escrito o nome do meu Model assim: USer. No meu localhost funcionava, mas na web dava problema.

Comment: Eu sei q vc já disse que acha q não é cache, mas tu experimentou `php artisan cahe:clear`?